# Using twitterOAuth for login scripts

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I recently started working with twitteroauth login, which seems to be working in the examples ([found here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth-example)) but not when I amalgamate the redirect.php and callback.php
Based on the script below (which is integrated in a bit of login script I've been working on) the second portion works fine (which is based on redirect.php), returning an oauth_token and oauth_verifier, but the first part (based on callback.php) isn't even initiating it seems. Which it should when Twitter redirects the user to the homepage.

Any ideas/suggestions folks?

```
session_start();
require_once('socialCodes.php');    //where I keep my app ID and Secret
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');

if (isset($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
 $connection = new TwitterOAuth($twAppID, $twAppSec, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";

  $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

  unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
 unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

 if (200 == $connection->http_code) {
        $userAccessToken = $access_token['oauth_token'];
     $userSecretToken = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
      $userID = $access_token['user_id'];
      $userName = $access_token['screen_name'];
    }

} else {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($twAppID, $twAppSec);
   $connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";

 $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('myhomepage');

 $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
 $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

  switch ($connection->http_code) {
     case 200:
        $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
        header('Location: ' . $url); 
        break;
   default:
   echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe the behavior you're experiencing a little more? What exactly is happening when you attempt to authenticate? (Where is the user redirected to, what error is displayed, if any?)

Comment: Initially, the user is asked to give permission to the application, and then is redirected to the site, where the site checks for oauth_token having been set, if thats the case it works with the oauth_token and everything else sent over by Twitter.

I can see that the oauth_token is set in the address bar, but it doesn't see it, and unfortunately I'm getting no error messages.

Comment: It's basically skipping the initial If statement.

Comment: Alright, caching issue, the script works after all, thanks for that ass @MalcolmDiggs

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a caching issue, and the script now works.